# push notifications to ios error

Tags: ios, iphone, notifications

i am trying to configure my iphone application to push notifications to ios device, i used this tutorial :

http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/

but i had an error in : exporting .p12 certificate, the error is :

> An error has occurred. Unable to export an item. In dark wake, no UI
>   possible.

anyone can help with this ? i really need it now

Note: i want to push notifications from my web server, just like facebook. how can i implement this ?

Comment: rebooting might help. http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/107603/not-able-to-export-private-key-from-keychain-mavericks

Comment: how are you exporting the certificate

Comment: yes restart helps, thanks :)